# Getting the result of a class to output in PHP

Tags: php, forms, class

I'm trying to use a class to calculate numbers and output them on the screen. The user enters numbers and then it calculates and outputs on the screen above the form.

I'm using the post method to post the form results to the page I'm on and then trying to use that in the Fibonacci class.

The numbers need to go through the class and then output the result based on what the user put in. I *think* most of this is correct, but something is holding me up that I can't quite figure out.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Fibonacci {

    //method to check numbers
function checkFibo(){

        $n1 = $_POST["n1"];
        $n2 = $_POST["n2"];
        $output = "";
        if($n1!=0 && $n2!=0){
            if($n2<$n1){
                echo "Your second number must be greater than the first. Try again";        
                $output="Your second number must be greater than the first. Try again";
            }
           else if($n1<0 || $n2<0){
                echo "Please enter only positive numbers";

                $output = "Please enter positive numbers";
            }
            else if (!(is_numeric($n1)) || !(is_numeric($n2))){
                echo "Please only enter positive numbers";
                $output="";
            }
            else{
                echo "The result of your request is shown below.";
                $output=$fibo->getFibo($n1,$n2);
                echo $output;
            }
        }
        else{
                echo "<p>Please enter good values</p>";
        }


    }

     // Method to calculate fibonacci
    function getFibo($n1 = 0, $n2 = 0) {
        $max=$n2 * 100;
        $output = "";
        while($z<=$max){
                 $z = $n1 + $n2;
                $output.=($z."<br />");
                $n1 = $n2;
                $n2 = $z;
        }
        return $output;
    }


} // End of Fibonacci class.


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Fibonacci</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)){
    $fib = new Fibonacci();
    echo "hello";
    echo $output;
} 


echo "<h2> Fibonacci Example </h2>";
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php\">";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>First Number</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"n1\"/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Second Number</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"n2\"/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"go!\"/></td>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";





?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `but something is holding me up` is not a valid question. Describe what you expect to happen and what actually does happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue.

```
$output=$fibo->getFibo($n1,$n2);
```

I think should be:

```
$output = $this->getFibo($n1,$n2);
```

To test, put an echo statement in the getFibo function to see if anything prints. You can also run var_dump of $output and see what that returns.

Also the line:

```
$fib = new Fibonacci();
echo "hello";
echo $output;
```

Should be:

```
$fib = new Fibonacci();
echo "hello";
$fib->getFibo();
```

You have another problem though. It's creating an infinite loop. You want to make sure that $z will always eventually be more than $max, or set a maximum loop count and break out one that max has been reached.

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether or not echoing $output in the HTML portion would echo the right thing. If it were a function I would return $output and then echo $fib, but since it's a class I'm not sure how to make that work.

Comment: If the function has echo $output, then when you call the function, you don't need to echo. You just call the function.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much! I needed to use $fib->checkFibo(); and it functioned as desired. I've been banging my head up against this for a week now.

Comment: No problem. glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it looks like the variable $output could be a problem.

```
$output.=($z."<br />");
```

You do a concatenation to `$output` without it actually being declared or set to begin with.

So maybe try making `$output = ""` before the while loop.

Comment: I get "hello" after hitting submit, which basically I put there just for me to be able to see the form did in fact post. However I do not get any of the other desired output. I updated my code and put it above, still not getting desired results.